# postgresql: A question on SELECT

Tags: postgresql, select

I've a query like

```
SELECT t3 FROM tbl_join WHERE t2=3 AND t1 in (1,2,3);
```

and the output is:

```
 t3 
----
  1
  1
(2 rows)
```

It gives only two rows as entry for t3 is not present. Is it possible to modify the SELECT query something like:

```
SELECT t3||0 FROM tbl_join WHERE t2=3 AND t1 in (1,2,3);
```

to get the result like

```
 t3 
----
  1
  1
  0
(3 rows)
```

I mean, is it possible to write a query where one can get output with no. of rows equal to the no. of arguments in `in clause`. If an entry is not present output should come as some constant value for the corresponding input

Comment: It seems as if you assume, that the values in t3 are in the same order, as (t1 in (1, 2, 3)), and (1,1,0) would mean no t1=3 value. But if you don't order your result set, you don't know, to which value 1, 1 and 0 belong.

Answer (score 1):

you want an outer join: something like

```
SELECT t.t3 
FROM (VALUES (1), (2), (3)) AS litvals 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_join as t 
    ON litvals.column1 = t.t1
WHERE t.t2=3
```

Edit:  Hmm.  when there is no corresponding row in `tbl_join` to match up with the `VALUES`, then `t2` is NULL, which of course is not equal to 3.  You could deal with this with a subselect:

```
SELECT t.t3 
FROM (VALUES (1), (2), (3)) AS litvals 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT * FROM tbl_join WHERE t2 = 3) AS t 
    ON litvals.column1 = tbl_join.t1
```

Comment: They'll probably want a [COALESCE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-conditional.html#AEN15541) in there too.

Comment: This gives only 2 rows.`SELECT t3 FROM (VALUES (1), (2), (3)) AS litvals JOIN tbl_join ON litvals.column1 = tbl_join.t1 WHERE t2=3;` Am I missing something

Comment: ohh... but... `db_test=# SELECT t3 FROM (VALUES (1), (2), (3)) AS litvals LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_join ON litvals.column1 = tbl_join.t1 WHERE t2=3;` is giving  2 rows :(